# ORA-01410 - Invalid ROWID while trying to UPDATE/DELETE in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently creating an app in Oracle APEX and for some unknown to me reason while trying perform UPDATE/DELETE action by clicking on 'edit' button in the report I get this error `'ORA-01410 - Invalid ROWID'` but only on 3 out of 10 tables. In those 7 everything works as intended. I've also tried performing these operations without using ROWID in report but it ended up not updating at all. Will be grateful for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show the queries that fail.  We have no idea what you have written.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There it is. The thing is that when I view the whole error_statement inside of 'where' clause isn't the correct item name like 'P7_ROWID' but instead there is 'where rowid=p_rowid'. I wanted to check how the select statement is created on other tables to compare but I don't know hot to do it.

Comment: You should at least at the statement which is shown in 8. ... DRUZ ....

Comment: That's what I said. I can see one that fails but I don't know how to check the select statements that are run for the working tables, so I can't compare the working and failing statements.

Comment: As a test, use the create page wizard to create a new form with report that uses ROWID for the PK. Don't change any of the default settings but test to see if it works.  Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Unfortunately that was probably the first thing I tried. And it didn't work out. Same issue every single time. I'm starting to believe that it has to be either a oracle bug or something weird happened to the database. I've also tried creating a completely new app and the result was identical.

Answer (score 1):

We had a simmilar (same?) issue and discovered that `ROWID` sometimes converts to a char string that has a special char in it like `+`. That char is seems to be wrongly interpreted in an autoload event of a form and thus this error is raised. We couldn't solve it so we switched to a different primary key for the form.

Comment: I've managed to find the issue within my query (by accident) - this situation was caused by a wrong JOIN which completely ruined subpages, but thanks for responding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

when you select the rowid from table convert it to varchar2 like the following
where ROWIDTOCHAR(rowid) = 'AAAUHLAAJAAAAM8AAD'
it will not return the ora error

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually was a wrong type of JOIN on tables, which for some reason I did not expect.